# Vaadin LoginForm Failure Handler Breaks login?error URL

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-security, vaadin, vaadin-flow

I'm using the Vaadin LoginForm with Spring Security in a Spring Boot project. By default it redirects to `/login?error` if authentication fails for any reason. I want to redirect for certain failures, specifically if the user hasn't validated their email yet. I'm trying to use the `failureHandler` feature to do this, but as soon as I create one, the `/login?error` URL suddenly requires the user to be authenticated, while `/login` functions as normal.

My login view:

```
@PageTitle("Login")
@Route("login", layout = MainLayout::class)
class LoginView : VerticalLayout(), BeforeEnterObserver {
    private val loginForm: LoginForm

    init {
        alignItems = FlexComponent.Alignment.CENTER
        className = "login-view"
        width = LumoUtility.Width.AUTO


        loginForm = loginForm { action = "login" }
        button("Register") {
            onLeftClick { ui.ifPresent { it.navigate("register")} }
        }
    }

    override fun beforeEnter(beforeEnterEvent: BeforeEnterEvent) {
        if (beforeEnterEvent.location.queryParameters.parameters.containsKey("error")) {
            loginForm.isError = true
        }
    }
}
```

My security configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
class SecurityConfiguration : VaadinWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {

    @Throws(Exception::class)
    override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {

        http.formLogin()
            .failureHandler(object : SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler() {
                override fun onAuthenticationFailure(
                    request: HttpServletRequest?,
                    response: HttpServletResponse?,
                    exception: AuthenticationException?
                ) {
                    super.onAuthenticationFailure(request, response, exception)
                }
            })

        super.configure(http)
        setLoginView(http, LoginView::class.java)
    }
```

As you can see, all I did was add a failureHandler in my security configuration function that simply calls the default failureHandler, but that is enough to break the `/login?error`. If I remove that failureHandler, then it works as expected and shows the `/login?error` URL when login fails.  How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You setting a `failureHandler` overrides the default of simply redirecting to `/login?error` (and automatically configuring this URL to not require authentication). Looking at the code you can only have one `AuthenticationFailureHandler`.

Comment: So how do I configure it to not need authentication?

Comment: `http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login?error").permitAll();`

Comment: Didn't work, I added that line right before my `http.formLogin()...` line.

Comment: Hmm, `AntPathRequestMatcher` doesn't consider the query string of a request URL, so `http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login").permitAll();` should be enough.

Comment: Still didn't work. I figure Vaadin is doing something in the way it configures everything that's causing it. I went though the `super.configure` method and nothing jumped out at me though.

Comment: Wait, I think it's working now. Not entirely sure what I did differently, but I guess there are certain combinations that don't work. The `antMatchers` call is important though.